# Can't recover my files after switching branch

Tags: git, commit

I have the following problem:

I think I was working on my remote branch und committed my changes.
I afterwards changed the branch to my local branch. (See in the pictures)

And since then my changes are missing. - but the thing is: I can't see my commits to my remote branch.

Does anyone know what happened here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJVXi.jpg)

Comment: "I think I was working on my remote branch" You cannot work on a remote branch. You can only work on a local branch.

Comment: I guess you may have committed to a branch other than you think. Check the reflog to see what has happened recently. But unless you did a reset or took untracked files out or your working directory, you didn't lose your files.

Comment: It would help if you would explain with some precision what actions you took or gave any sort of details at all.

Comment: p.s. You should copy/paste text output here directly as text rather than posting a screenshot.

Comment: @theherk The output from `git reflog` in the screenshot already shows the exact actions that lead up to the problem.

Comment: I'm suggesting like you, that those details should be provided here in text, [rather than in a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2081835). I just don't follow "enter image description here" links, so I overlooked it. And your answer is great.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the `git reflog` output in your image, I see `HEAD@{30}` with a message that seems to be the commit you want to restore. You can do `git checkout HEAD@{30}` to check out the commit. Be sure to only do this if your local copy is clean. You may want to commit or stash any changes you currently have.

Now after you do this checkout, you can do whatever you want, such as create a new branch, cherry-pick, etc.

Alternatively to restore the commit to your current branch, you can do `git checkout easyWithNextJS` to get your local branch. Then run `git reflog` again to find the commit and `git cherry-pick HEAD@{##}` and replace `##` with the correct number that you find in `git reflog`.

---

It looks like you checked out the remote tracking branch `origin/easyWithNextJS` directly rather than creating a new local branch. This put you in so-called "detached HEAD" mode. When you make commits in thist state, they are not associated with any branch and will be "lost" when you check out an actual branch. To prevent this in the future, make sure you create a new branch when checking out a remote tracking branch. The easiest way to do this is to do `git checkout -b <branch-name>` where `<branch-name>` is the same as a branch on your remote. Note that you should not include the `origin/` prefix here.

I suggest you read more about remote tracking branches to understand how they work.

Comment: The right search phrase is "detached HEAD mode" rather than "headless mode", but otherwise, this is the answer, yes.